# python appengine authorisation or authorization

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, authorization, tipfy

Having settled on OpenID for authentication, I've been looking at authorisation frameworks for app-engine with the following requirements:

- be able to create and edit groups of users
- has built in permissions such as add, edit, delete
- has sensible defaults, e.g creator of an object can edit / delete but others can't

knowing enough to know that security permissions are a bad idea to self implement without a massive brain, i've been reading through django  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ and tipfy http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/acl/ to choose one that has already been cooking in the oven for a while.

It's not obvious which will be easier / more extensible so I was hoping to be able to call on experience, recommendations or other suggestions to make a sensible decision?

Comment: "knowing enough to know that security permissions are a bad idea to self implement without a massive brain" - I think you're confusing that with implementing cryptographic security. There's nothing particularly complicated about rolling your own permissions system.

Comment: @Nick Johnson yes cryptography is hard too but having been a pen tester in my previous life, I can say from experience that many people get authorisation very wrong.

Comment: I agree, but I don't think a pre-rolled authorisation library is going to help those people much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that there are a lot of problems with django ORM and Google app engine datastore, and http://www.tipfy.org/ says that it is **made specifically for Google App Engine** I must suggest typfy.

Answer (score 1):

2 pretty good frameworks I tried that have authorisation are [GAEFramework](http://www.gaeframework.com) and [web2py](http://www.web2py.com). They are both easier to get started with than tipfy. I hope you like these.